# openjdk JVM Crash to SIGSEGV

Tags: java

Our server hung because of a SIGSEGV fault..

My program script is killed by the system once a week. There is no problem with the system resources and it is relatively sufficient. The following is the error log. I hope you can help analyze the cause of the problem, thank you
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

```
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000fffeef35c9a4, pid=2369121, tid=0x0000fffc969ff1c0
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_242-b08) (build 1.8.0_242-b08)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.242-b08 mixed mode linux-aarch64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# j  io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.newInstance(I)Lio/netty/buffer/PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf;+6
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/hd/hd-bpm-cloud-server/core or core.2369121
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000fffe60003000):  JavaThread "redisson-netty-17-11" [_thread_in_Java, id=2369414, stack(0x0000fffc96800000,0x0000fffc96a00000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x00000008bbea5f6b
```

full log file：https://github.com/kernelsky/kubernetes/blob/master/hs_err_pid2369121.log
This file contains jvm indicators, status before being killed, thread information, etc.
The same problem still exists in the upgraded version of openjdk

I am curious to know what could be the root cause of this?

Any help is highly appreciated..Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this [issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/12119) could be related. Both are having a crash using netty and redisson. Just gave a quick look at the log and seems to me that many threads were started and are also blocked. If that is happening, it could be a thread starvation, but not sure if that is causing the crash. If you have monitoring tools, you could see how the resources are being consumed. There is also a core dump file that is hosted in the server, have you checked it?

Comment: What server are you using? A cloud provider? Bare metals? Operative system? Virtual machine? Docker? Please add more details about the context. If you have a dashboard of resources consumed, it could help to see what is happening. I mean not only cpu, memory and network. Also jvm resources

Comment: system：Kylin  Linux 4.19.90-23.8.v2101.ky10.aarch64   ARMv8 CPU ，
The core file has been analyzed, but what is the problem is not found out，When there is a problem, the cpu and memory will rise in a straight line, but the cpu is only 100% of the single core, and there is still room for system memory

Comment: what about the jvm metrics? memory, cpu, threads, garbage collector, method calls, etc.

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. A segmentation fault happens when you access memory that isn't yours, like a null pointer in C (not a `NullPointerException` in Java). This looks like a problem in the JVM to me. Can you upgrade?

Comment: It is more likely to be a problem with non-OpenJDK native code libraries ... or something using `Unsafe` uncorrectly.  If you look at the netty issue tracker you will see examples of this kind of thing.  Unfortunately, there is little that we can do to help you.  You can try upgrading your Java to a more recent version of Java 8, but that may not help.